# Updating sql records

Tags: c#, sql-server

Now I add this tables with these columns:

```
DrugID, BatchNo, ManufacreDate, ExpireDate, Quantity.
```

Note: `(DrugID, BatchNo)` constitute the primary key.

For example: there are 2 records as follow:

```
(101, 1234, 1-7-2014, 1-7-2016, 50)
(101, 7654, 1-7-2015, 1-7-2017, 80)
```

If, as example, one customer wants 80 item from drug with drugID=101, how could I update the table so that the first record will be removed, the second one will remain but the quantity will be modified to 30?

Any help, please?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no first and second row, unless a column specifies that ordering.  What column specifies the ordering?

Answer (score 0):

The approach to solving this is to calculate the cumulative quantity of each drug.  Then compare the cumulative amount to the desired amount to determine the rows that need updating.

The rest is a bit of arithmetic.  In SQL Server 2012+, the code looks like:

```
declare @val int = 80;

with t as (
      select t.*,
             sum(qty) over (partition by drugid order by batchno) as cumeqty
      from t
     )
update t
    set qty = (case when cumeqty - @val < 0 then 0
                    else cumeqty - @val
               end)
    where (cumeqty - @val) < qty;
```

In earlier versions, you have to work a bit harder to get the cumulative quantity, but the idea is the same.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ddf61/1) is an example of the code (or something very similar) working in SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @user3361967 . . . Me too, but your comment if very vague.  How does it not work?

Comment: I tried it in sql serevr. the record with condition:  where (cumeqty - @val) > qty; does not make the Quantity = 0.